problemas con webpush. No veo la notificacion
Estoy siguiendo un tutorial en el que se hace lo siguiente:
console.log('Service worker registered');

self.addEventListener('push', e => {
    const data = e.data.json();
    console.log('Push received:', data);
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
        body: data.message
    });
});

En la consola puedo ver los datos: Push received:
{title: 'my custom notificaction', message: 'hello world'}
message
:
"hello world"
title
:
"my custom notificaction"
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
pero no puedo ver la notificacion.
Ya active los permisos de notificacion y reinicie el servidor. Tambien probe en otro navegador.
Cual puede ser el problema?

¿Están activadas las notificaciones en tu navegador?

sisi...........................
